# List of active sessions in wicket

Tags: java, tomcat, wicket

I need to get list of active wicket session. Now I am saving all new session in override method newSession() and this session was being removed when session was being invalidated.  But this method had lots of problems. How I understand this method was very rude hack and if you know another method, I will be grateful. (I use wicket v1.5.4 and tomcat v7.0.25 )

**Update**

Thank for your answers, but I need to get list of WICKET session (WebSession). I added HttpSessionListener with static maps of WebSessions and HttpSessions (with synchronization). This way is better than my and doesn't have old problems but it's looks like hack too :(. Do you have any idea about getting list of wicket sessions?

Comment: Do you need the list for monitoring purposes? If so then some tool can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242958/best-tools-to-monitor-tomcat

Comment: @BorisPavlović partially you're right. It's need for monitoring page, but I use my own implementation of WebSession and don't know how to convert tomcat's object to wicket session object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would it be acceptable with a simple Listener instead, something like this?

```
public class SessionCounterListener implements HttpSessionListener {

  private static int totalActiveSessions;

  public static int getTotalActiveSession(){
    return totalActiveSessions;
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    totalActiveSessions++;
 }

  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    totalActiveSessions--;
  } 
}


<web-app ...>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>SessionCounterListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

There is also an example from the "Wicket in action" book [here](http://code.google.com/p/wicketinaction/source/browse/trunk/book-wicket-in-action/src/main/java/wicket/in/action/chapter14/section_14_4/Index.html?r=140)

Comment: +1, but shouldn't access to `totalActiveSessions` be synchronized or `AtomicInteger` used? I don't think servlet specification says anything about concurrent access to session listeners.

Comment: You're probably right @TomaszNurkiewicz, in a real world application I would probably synchronize it :)

Comment: I have saved list of HttpSessions, but I don't know how to convert those sessions to wickets sessions (WebSession), becouse I can't find method for getting this list of wickets sessions

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use JMX. If you browse to:

```
Catalina:type=Manager,context=/your_war_context,host=localhost
```

Under *Operations* you will find `listSessionIds()` method.